# Validating Resultant Structures of Computational Quantum Chemistry Optimisations

Tags: computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory

I have tried finding sources (publications, websites, blogs) that outline the logic of accepting the resultant structure of optimisation. I understand using a Hessian to determine if the structure is a local minimum. I am more interested in understanding what steps I should take to make sure that my functional and basis set are accurately determining the bond lengths and angles. I would need to know for benchmark testing so I can choose a functional and basis set that balances accuracy and cost.

Are there any resources that explain this type of process in-depth?

EDIT:

I found these answers on this forum from LordStryker and Martin that both give pretty thorough explanations for how to validate structures and choose a good functional for a project

[Dipole moment of cis-2-butene](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16342/dipole-moment-of-cis-2-butene)

[DFT Functional Selection Criteria](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27302/dft-functional-selection-criteria/27418#27418)

Comment: Do you have questions that go beyond the ones you have already found? If so, please be more specific. Currently it's hard to add to that,